# Cannot add existing file to csproj with VS2015

Tags: .net, git, visual-studio-2015

guys

I cloned solution (Solution was created with VS 2013) from git and modified it with VS2015 community edition, after that I removed VS2015 community edition and installed VS 2015 Enterprise edition (I wanted to use IntelliTest). After install of VS 2015 Enterprise Edition I cannot to add existing or add new class, interface to all projects from solution.

I tried to uninstall and install VS2015 Enterprise Edition but it is not helped me.

I cleaned up cache for VS, but it is not helped me too.

How can resolve this issue?

Comment: What does "I cannot" mean? Is there an error, does Visual Studio crach or what happens? Please be more specific.

Comment: When I try to add a new class, then VS will show error message that file with such name is exist, but it is not true.

Comment: When I try to add existing class to cs project (I created this file before using free commander) then VS will not display any error message but will not add file.

Comment: The file might not exist in project but might in the file system.  Above the file list in solution explorer, the Show All Files button will reveal this (3 document images style icon).  If you try to add a file that exists on file system you get that message.